# How do I find the minimum value of a binary tree?

Tags: objective-c, tree, nodes

I'm trying to find the minimum value of a binary tree. Every time I run my code I get a long 5 digit number like '32675'. I'm pretty sure my understanding of pointers is wrong, but I'm not positive. If I could get some advice I'd really appreciate it. Thanks!

**Node definition**

```
@interface Node:NSObject {
    @property (nonatomic, strong) Node *left;
    @property (nonatomic, strong) Node *right;
    @property (nonatomic, assign) int *value;
}

-(id)initWithValue:(int)val {
    self = [super init];
    if(self) {
        self.value = &(val);
        self.left = nil;
        self.right = nil;
    }
    return self;
}
```

**Insert Algorithms for Tree**

```
-(void)insertValue:(int)value {
    Node *node = [[Node alloc] initWithValue:value];
    [self insertNode:node];
}

-(void)insertNode:(Node *)node {
    if (root == nil) {
        root = node;
    } else {
        [node insertNode:node];
    }
}
```

**Insert Algorithms for Node**

```
-(void)insertNode:(Node *)node{
    if (node.value < self.value) {
        [self insertOnLeft:node];
    } else {
        [self insertOnRight:node];
    }
}

-(void)insertOnLeft:(Node *)node {
    if (self.left == nil) {
        self.left = node;
    } else {
        [self.left insertNode:node];
    }
}

-(void)insertOnRight:(Node *)node {
    if (self.right == nil) {
        self.right = node;
    } else {
        [self.right insertNode:node];
    }
}
```

**3 values go in to my tree:**

```
[tree insertValue:4];
[tree insertValue:6];
[tree insertValue:2];

int min = [tree findMinimum];
```

**Tree's findMinimum method is called**

```
-(int)findMinimum {
    assert(root != nil);
    return [root findMinimum];
}
```

**Which call's root's findMinimum - root is a node**

```
-(int)findMinimum {
    Node *node = self;
    int min = 0;
    while (node != nil) {
        min = *(node.value);
        node = node.left;
    }
    return min;
}
```

Comment: It will help people help you if you add the definition of your `Node` type and the algorithm used by `insertValue`

Comment: certainly, I added more information above. Thanks!

Comment: Your property `value` should undoubtedly be of type `int` and not `int *` - it is a primitive value not an (object) pointer. So your `initWithValue:` is probably doing something wrong, as is your `findMinimum`. Add the code for your `initWithValue` if this comment has given you enough of a clue to find your problem.

Comment: that did the trick, thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your are filling your tree not with integers but with stack addresses which are immediately invalid with this code:

```
self.value = &(val);
```

Here `val` is a parameter variable, which will disappear as soon as the method returns. Taking its address should only be done in rare circumstances and that address should **never** be stored in a location which outlives `val`.

Change the type of the `value` property of `Node` to `int` and remove the uses of address of (`&`) and indirection (`*`) associated with that property.

HTH

Comment: Thanks so much! This was super helpful. Stupid mistake putting the & operator in there with Xcode's auto-fix and me not really paying attention. Thanks for the thorough explanation!

Answer (score 1):

The assignment in the initializer of a pointer to the parameter won't work.  Unless you have a good reason not to, actually allocate the `int` into the `Node` structure by declaring it an `int`, not an `int *`.  So your initializer will look like this:

```
-(id)initWithValue:(int)val {
    self = [super init];
    if(self) {
        self.value = val;
    }
    return self;
}
```

**EDIT** If you weren't sorting on insert (which I missed in the OP), you could instead search for the min recursively as follows:

```
-(int)findMinimum {
    if (self.left && self.right)
        return MIN([self.left findMinimum], [self.right findMinimum]);
    else if (self.left)
        return [self.left findMinimum];
    else if (self.right)
        return [self.right findMinimum];
    else
        return self.value;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, you as well as @CRD provided the correct answer with the change from int * to int...silly mistake....also thank you for your recurisive minimum algorithm. I'll give it a shot!

Comment: The tree is already sorted by design, you don't need to take the minimum of the left & right subtrees - the OP's original algorithm is fine (min is leftmost, max is rightmost).

Comment: @CRD, you're right.  I missed the sort on insertion because of the question format.   Will fix that now.

Comment: @danh apologies for my poor format...appreciate the help none the less :)